# Handling Sparse Data Frames - algorithm selection

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, sparse-matrix, logistic-regression

I am new to machine learning/statistical modelling.

I am trying to run a classification on a highly sparse dataset with 100 features, most of which are categorical (TRUE/FALSE) with the remaining values missing. To handle missing values, I filled the missing spots with the text 'Nothing', thereby creating a new level.

Next, I am trying to run a logistic regression using a penalty (glmnet package). When I check the coefficients, I see dummy variables corresponding to 'Nothing' having the higher coefficients.

How should I remove these coefficients? What would be a better approach to this?

Or should I just use trees? Please suggest the best way forward.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems strange that your Nothing labels are getting the higher coefficients.  Are these cases biased toward particular outcomes, or perhaps you are using multiple data sources and this particular source is biased towards a high or low range?

Comment: Hi Matthew. I am using a single dataset. The 'Nothing' cases correspond to missing data. I was not sure how else to handle the missing values, since the matrix is extremely sparse.

Comment: I think you should ask this question on stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: But don't repost the question; you can "flag" it as "off topic," then it will give you several options, one of which will be "migrate." Then you can ask that it be migrated to the stats site.